# Pusher - How to set channel_auth_endpoint for two or more pusher objects?

Tags: pusher

Based on the [docs](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users),

> The destination of the authentication request can be configured by
>   setting a static property on the Pusher object.
>
> `Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = '/pusher_auth.php';`

However, what if you have two or more pusher instances in a page? How do you set them differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set two different auth endpoints for two different `Pusher` instances right now as the property is a static one.

There is a plan to move away from such static properties but no timeline. If you have a requirement for this I'd recommend submitting a pull request since the Pusher JavaScript Library is open source:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js

Comment: Ok. I see that this is not an implemented feature yet. Guess I have to do some workarounds. But thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

As leggetter said, you can create two instances of pusher referenced to different vars such as:

```
var pusher1 = new Pusher('<your_app_key>');
pusher1.channel_auth_endpoint = '/pusher1_auth.php';

var pusher2 = new Pusher('<your_app_key>');
pusher2.channel_auth_endpoint = '/pusher2_auth.php';
```

At least thats how I did it.